# ¿Como puedo cambiar el relieve de un botón al pulsar otro?/Python

Tags: python, tkinter, botón

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que cuando le das clic a un botón te muestra objetos, y al pulsar el otro la función **limpiador_de_frames** se encarga de quitar los objetos que haya en el Frame para insertar los nuevos.
Lo que quiero es que si el usuario pulsa un botón este se le cambie el relieve a **SUNKEN** para que sepa en que opción esta actualmente, y que  hasta que no le des click al otro botón no se cambie el relieve **SUNKEN**.

```
from tkinter import *

v = Tk()
v.geometry("240x150+500+200")
v.title("Prueba")


f1= Frame(v, bg="grey15")
f1.place(x=20, y= 10, width=200, height=80)


def limpiador_de_frames():
        for i in f1.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()

def op_1():

    limpiador_de_frames()
    c2 = Entry(f1, bg="white")
    c2.place(x=20, y= 10)


def op_2():

    limpiador_de_frames()
    c1 = Entry(f1, bg="white")
    c1.place(x=20, y= 30)




bt1 = Button(v, text="1", command=op_1, bg="grey15", fg="white")
bt1.config(overrelief=GROOVE, relief=FLAT)
bt1.place(x=20, y= 100, height=20, width=60)

bt2 = Button(v, text="2", command=op_2, bg="grey15", fg="white")
bt2.config(overrelief=GROOVE, relief=FLAT)
bt2.place(x=90, y= 100, height=20, width=60)

v.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso es fácil simplemente tiene que poner este codigo en la funcion de el btn1 `bt1.config(relief=SUNKEN, bd=5)` y al presionar el boton bt1 cambiara el relieve del boton bt1, tienes que darle un borde para que se note que cambio el relieve.

```
def relieve():
   for i in v.winfo_children():
       i.config(relief=SUNKEN, bd=5)
```

espero te pueda servir

Comment: Hola, si funciona pero si tengo muchos botones entonces me toca repetir código, yo pensaba en una función para invocarla las veces que necesite y reutilizar el código.

Comment: esto te puede servir  lo unico es que cambia todos los bordes la ventana